# InputAccessoryView Button Touch Event Triggers Desired Event Plus Event of View Under Accessory View

Tags: cocoa-touch, events, uibutton, uiresponder

I have an input accessory view with a button. When the keyboard appears, the input accessory view covers another view that is touch enabled. Not only is the button triggering the desired event handler, but it is triggering the event handler of the view below it, which is not desired.

I think I have read somewhere about how touch events may do this and that it can be stopped. Right now, I don't know the terminology to search for.

Comment: This is me: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Any insight?